# Update URL with two dropdown list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do have two select box like this.

```
<select class="" id="sender" name="sender">
    <option value="">---Select sender ---</option>
    <option value="1">Corliss Barrie</option>
    <option value="2">Marcie Nava</option>
    <option value="3">Weston Bryand</option>
    <option value="4">Osvaldo Lasker</option>
    <option value="5">Regan Ruckman</option>
</select>

<select class="" id="reciever" name="reciever">
    <option value="">---Select sender ---</option>
    <option value="1">Araceli Scheff</option>
    <option value="2">Assunta Marsch</option>
    <option value="3">Yang Wengerd</option>
    <option value="4">Branden Purtee</option>
    <option value="5">Krystal Fresquez</option>
</select>
```

My question is I need to update the url with this two select box values, only if both dropdown selected.

I can do it for one dropdown like below, but not sure how to do it with two drop down.

```
$('#sender').change(function(){
    var url = "?sender="+$(this).val();
    window.location = url;
});
```

But my expected url is something similar to this:

```
?sender=value&reciever=value
```

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can pretty easy outsource the logic into one function that only changes url if both values are given

```
$('#sender, #receiver').change(changeUrl);


function changeUrl(){
    if($('#receiver').val() != "" && $('#sender').val() != "" ){
        url = "?sender="+$('#sender').val()+"&receiver="+$('#receiver').val();
        window.location = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked this code but there is a problem. when I select one dropdown page is reloading and other value automatically set to 0. like this `sender=0&receiver=5` and wise versa  `sender=3&receiver=0`

Answer (score 0):

Just add another event listener and a conditional:

```
function changeURL(){
    if($('#sender').val()!="" &&$('#receiver').val()!=""){
        var url = "?sender="+$(this).val()+'&receiver="+$('#receiver').val();
        window.location = url;
    }
}
$('#sender').change(changeURL);
$('#receiver').change(changeURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/nnfggdom/5/). Added a common class `url` to both `select` element. And then do functionality on change event.

```
$('.url').change(function(){
    var sender = $('#sender').val();
    var receiver = $('#reciever').val(); 
    if(sender !== '' && receiver !== '') {
      var url = "?sender=" + sender + "&reciever=" + receiver;
      window.location = url;
    }
});
```

Comment: There are many ways to handle this. You can see some more valid answer posted for this question as well.

Comment: I checked this but when I select a value from first dropdown page is reloding and set 0 as other dropdown value. URL looks like this `&sender=0&reciever=3`

Comment: I need to page reload if both dropdown select correctly. not one.

Comment: It's working fine for me [here](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/nnfggdom/5/). When I choose both it's redirecting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96805/discussion-between-user3733831-and-deepakb).

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
<select class="changeurl" id="sender" name="sender">
<option value="0">---Select sender ---</option>
<option value="1">Corliss Barrie</option>
<option value="2">Marcie Nava</option>
<option value="3">Weston Bryand</option>
<option value="4">Osvaldo Lasker</option>
<option value="5">Regan Ruckman</option>
</select>

<select class="changeurl" id="reciever" name="reciever">
<option value="0">---Select reciever ---</option>
<option value="1">Araceli Scheff</option>
<option value="2">Assunta Marsch</option>
<option value="3">Yang Wengerd</option>
<option value="4">Branden Purtee</option>
<option value="5">Krystal Fresquez</option>
</select>
```

And your jquery code will like this:

```
$('.changeurl').on('change', function (e) {
if( $('#sender').val()!="0" && $('#reciever').val()!="0" ){
var newURLString = window.location.href + "?sender=" + $('#sender').val() + "&reciever=" + $('#reciever').val();

window.location.href = newURLString;  
}
});
```